# Blazor Server Custom Re-connect UI - Display Retry Attempts

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor Server application, which uses custom 're-connecting' UI elements for when the circuits are disconnected.  And this is working as it should.

However, in doing so I've lost the '1 of 8' text showing how many attempts have been made.

I've looked through the Microsoft documentation on custom UI:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/signalr?view=aspnetcore-3.1#reflect-the-server-side-connection-state-in-the-ui

... but there's no mention of displaying the number of attempts.

Has anyone successfully displayed the number of attempts in a custom UI and can point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 2):

After digging around in blazor.server.js I found the following line of code:

```
  Ln.CurrentAttemptId = "components-reconnect-current-attempt";
```

... and added an element with that Id like so:

```
            <span id="components-reconnect-current-attempt">Number of Attempts here...</span>
```

...and got the result I was looking for!

Full sample div for future reference:

```
        <div class="d-flex-row text-center fw-bold">
            (Attempt
            <span id="components-reconnect-current-attempt"></span>
            of
            <span id="components-reconnect-max-retries"></span>
            )
        </div>
```